# Slowing Down Slideshow Effect on MegaMenu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, megamenu

I have this megamenu working, but it's clunky. So I'm trying to slow down the slidedown effect with some additional jQuery (which is the second section of code you see below). So far I seem to be grabbing the wrong elements though. What elements should I be placing in the last section of jQuery code in order to target the drop-menu items, rather than the whole menu? Right now the whole menu vanishes when clicked, rather than the individual elements.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
    var menu = jQuery('#mega-menu-wrap-secondary'); // change this to target your menu

    // do not edit below this line
    jQuery('li.mega-menu-item', menu).on('open_panel', function(e) {
        var sub_menu = jQuery('.mega-sub-menu', jQuery(this));
        menu.css('margin-bottom', sub_menu.height());
    });
    jQuery('li.mega-menu-item', menu).on('close_panel', function(e) {
        menu.css('margin-bottom', '');
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".mega-menu").mouseenter( function() {
        jQuery("li.mega-menu-item").slideDown(1000);
    });

    jQuery(".mega-menu").mouseleave( function() {
        jQuery("li.mega-menu-item").slideUp(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: All that will do is change the speed of the drop-down. That's not my problem.

Comment: so what do you mean by slow down the slidedown effect ???

Comment: Without the second jQuery section, the megamenu just clunks down really quickly. So I'm trying to customize the second jQuery section above, so that the correct elements are grabbed, and thus it slows and smooths out the effect of the drop-down. The second jQuery part above wasn't part of the original code. I am trying to add it so as to slow/smooth the effect. Right now the whole menu disappears after being clicked, rather than the individual elements.